# Explanation why Height=100% breaks design

Tags: html, css, height

I have a problem with the Height Tag in CSS. I want the page to be displayed without any scrollbars and just can't figure out why when i change "height" in the body tag from 99% to 100% suddenly scrollingbars appear and break the design.

I want to know why this happens and what's the reason for it.

thanks!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">

html {
    height:100%;
}

body {
    height: 99%;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-top:0px;

}

.gallerytitle {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    font-family: serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: left;
}

.fullgallerytitle {
text-align: left;
font-family: sans-serif;
font-size: 12px;}

.events{
position: absolute;
font-family: sans-serif;
font-size: 12px;
top: 20px;
right: 20px;}

/* Center Text Section */

.area {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;

  position: relative;
}

.middlespace {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  display: table;
}

.middlespace p {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
}



.bottom-left {

    position: absolute;
    font:sans-serif;
    bottom: 15px;
    left: 15px;
}



.contact {
    font-size: 11px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    border-bottom: 1px black dotted;
}

.exhibitiontitle {
    color: #d4d4d4;
    font-style: italic;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}

.contact {
    font-size: 11px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    border-bottom: 1px black dotted;
}

.bold {
    font-family: serif;
}


.about {
    font-size: 11px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}


.address {
font-size: 11px;
border-bottom: 1px grey dotted;
}




.bottom-right {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 15px;
    right:15px;
      font-style: italic;
    color: #8e8e8e;
    font-size: 11px;
}

.openinghours {
    font-style: italic;
    color: #8e8e8e;
    font-size: 11px;
    }
.subscribebutton
{

height:10px;
font-size: 9px;

}

.subscribebox
{

height:10px;
font-size: 9px;

}



</style>

<title>XYZ</title>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="gallerytitle">XYZ<br /></div>
    <div class="events">LOREM</div>




<div class="bottom-left">
        <span class="about">

            <span class="bold">XYZ</span> is a project by XZY.&nbsp;&nbsp;&#124;&nbsp;
            <span="address">Website Information</span> &mdash; <a href="mailto:info@info.eu">info@info.com</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;


        </span>
</div>


<div class="bottom-right">
    <span class="openinghours">Open by Appointment</span><span class="">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;sponsored by XYZ</span>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Padding and margins most likely.

Comment: @TheZ He doesn't use paddings and the only margin he uses is a horizontal margin. When I read the question right, he has a problem with vertical scrollbars. 
@ Roland I can't reproduce your issue. Can you make a JSFiddle? When I change it to 100%, no scrollbars appear.

Comment: You don't by any chance have a link to a live website, do you?

Comment: @JonnyBurger Browsers usually add Body padding/margins by default. When you make the height 100% it does not take these into account and suddenly your page is 100%+padding/margins and scrollbars appear. Just as described.

Comment: @TheZ surprisingly I never had this issue with `height: 100%`. I can also not reproduce it in Chrome. If this would be the issue, the solution would be `body { box-sizing: border-box; }`, right? (Don't forget to prefix)

Comment: the issue was indeed that firefox seems to auto. add a slight "margin-bottom" - so setting it to 0px fixed it. never heard about box-sizing. thx everyone!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is also bottom margin on the body.

```
body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 0 0 20px;    
}
```

Though you should consider using a css reset such as eric meyers reset or normalize

Comment: But yeah good catch, the `bottom-margin` might be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Replacing your body style with this should solve the issue :

```
body {
height: 100%;
margin-left: 20px;
margin:0px;
```

}

Comment: The last `margin` declaration will overwrite `margin-left`.

Comment: `margin:0` will cancel `margin-left`. And OP said he cannot change the `height` to 100%.

Answer (score 0):

It breaks the page because you use 99% of the page, then you move everything to the right of 20px. it moves the 99% outside and use more. here is the solution, i think both of them work :

```
body {
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-right: -20px;
    margin-top:0px;
}
```

or

```
body {
    height: 100%;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: -20px;
    margin-top:0px;
}
```